# javascript sending value to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Wondering if anyone can help me out here.

I have this javascript which is sending id to a php page to retrieve details.

```
    <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
             displayListings();

        $("#listTb").on("click", "tr", function() {
            var url = "listingDetail.php?listingid="+this.id;
            alert("directing to : " + url);
            window.open(url);
          });
         });
    </script>
```

When I click on the tr, I do get a pop up message saying

listingDetail.php?listingid=1

Now on the php, im trying to do this to retrieve the id:

```
    <body>
      <?php
          $listingid = 0;
          if(!isset($_REQUEST['listingid'])){
              exit;
          }else{
              $listingId = $_REQUEST['listingid'];
          }   
       ?>
    </body>

    <table id="listTb" >
       <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td>....<?php echo htmlentities($listingid); ?>.......</td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>

    </table>
```

It prints 0 here instead of 1.

Im confused why this isint working. Please help !

Answer (score 0):

`$listingid` and `$listingId` are different vars.

```
        ^-lower case   ^-upper case
```